# Access Paypal Account Details (Monthly Sale Reports) through API?

Tags: paypal

Is there any way we can get access to our paypal account details (like monthly/daily sales report) using its API?

We have several paypal accounts that we are using for several ecommerce websites and we need report on everyday that how much sale done yesterday so looking for any idea that its possible or not and if yes than basic idea about how.

We are using paypal regular payment option to pay using paypal shopping cart.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it is too late but since no one have answered it so thought of sharing. Please check this url for details https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_reporting_guide.pdf.